Missing the required "name" field
Is there a way that dart pub creates a pubspec.yaml to install the CSV module?
$ dart pub add csv
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/home/michal/Downloads/shazam".
$ touch pubspec.yaml

$ dart pub add csv
Error on line 1, column 1 of pubspec.yaml: Missing the required "name" field.


For dart pub add command to work you must need a pubspec.yaml file in the current directory. The pubspec.yaml file keeps track of the dependencies and other related information about your Flutter/Dart project.
By said that, I want to clarify that the pubspec.yaml file will be auto-generated from the very beginning of the project. The file will be generated when you start project by running either:
dart create <project_name>

Or
flutter create <project_name>

So you don't manually have to create the file. Anyway, if you want to manually create the file make sure it contains name, and enviornment properties in it.
name: <your_project_name>

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.0.0"

Check this article for detailed overview of the pubspec.yaml file: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec.
